# Wordpress css how to remove something

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm creating a website using wordpress but the template I am using is doing something I do not want it to.
Using the pricing table function on one of my pages but it is coming up with random pence. I've looked at the html generated and there is a "span class price - secondary line which seems to be where it is coming from. Within wordpress I cannot alter this for some reason.

Is there some trick with css that will get rid of it?

Comment: Can you provide extra information? Image describing what should be removed, html code containing the element(s) to remove etc.

Comment: Good point Alexei, I'll put up the html in question shortly. Thanks

Comment: Here is the html that I need help with. Thanks all.

Comment: Here is a section of the html.                                                    
  <table class="pricing-table  ">
   <tr>
     <td class="  pricing-table-item ">


      <div class="table-header"><h3>Standart</h3></div>
      <div class="table-price">

           <span class="currency">$</span>
           <span class="price-main">99</span>
           <span class="price-secondary">90.000000000001<br><span class="period">monthly</span></span>